# GridView doesn't show second row

Tags: android, gridview

My project's gridview shows only 5 photos and in one row while I have added 10 photos which should be diplayed in two rows.Why is my gridview not showing second row.Is this problem because of many layouts?I have posted xml code and java code....

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout16"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout17"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout18"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout19"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFD801">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Hyderabad Hotshots"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout19"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/hello"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout18"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="xyz"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout17"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</RelativeLayout>
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout16"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="5"


        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        >
    </GridView>



</RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout15"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="CAMPAIGN SCHEDULE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



</RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout14"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout13"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:text="@string/hello3"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

TeamDetails.java

```
public class TeamDetails extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.team_popup);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context mContext;
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbIds[position];
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null){
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            }
            else{
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }

        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.ply1, R.drawable.ply2,
                R.drawable.ply3, R.drawable.ply4,
                R.drawable.ply5, R.drawable.ply6,
                R.drawable.ply7, R.drawable.ply8,
                R.drawable.ply9, R.drawable.ply10
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="150dp"
```

and that works fine for me :)

Comment: which view you changed height, can u tell me is it `LinerLayout` or `GridView` @user39.4345